# Database of weakly typed objects

Tags: json, database, algorithm, store, nosql

I want to organize some part of my system, but i can't choose convenient form for data representation for interaction with my app.
So i have some local "repository" of data object, descripted as follows:

```
Object1
{ id = TypeId, field1 = value1, otherObjectSpecifedField = value2 ... }
...
```

There are many objects (for example 1000) of many types (for example 50). Each type have it own UniqueId and his own description and set of fields.

Next thing is that for **each** object i have a set of filters, which corresponds that this object is actual right now. It looks like this:

```
Filter
{ filterName1 = filterValue, filterName2 < filterValue }
Object // filter is applied for this object
{ ... }
```

The process of using this "repository":

1. In my app i have application states, which means filters from above.
   Example: application localization can be 'en' (my application knows this value and can change it on start) and we have filter, named 'localization' and in our repository we can use it like this:

   `Filter { localization = 'en'}
   Object1 { ... } // this object i should choose when localization is en`
2. When my app decides to check which set of obects is actual right now it cames to repository and asks it: "Here you an TypeId and please, walk through each filter+object pair and say what object is actual by filters. If you need to resolve some filter values (localization from example above) i will resolve them for you".
3. Then repository walks through each object and compare which is actual by filters now, and which is not and give actual to app. So he check every filter of every object and gives it only if all of them is actual and he did it in runtime.

In current implementation this set of fiters + objects is stored in xml file in very specific xml format, which is comfortably to read from app, but very hard to maintain by human. And i think that there is some place to optimization of all process. I think we can delegate of walking through Objects and comparing it filters to someone else.
Now i think in side of NoSQL document oriented databases. Because each Object has his unique structure and maybe using select routine i can choose what i need.

Maybe someone have any suggestions about that type of database organization? Maybe you know some specific data structure for that type of data?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I've missed something, because it looks to me like you have a number of different types of objects: one type per `TypeId`. If that's so, then I think this can be done with a standard SQL database, assuming that the fields within an object have a consistent type. If not, it can still be done with a NoSQL database.

In a SQL database, you would use a separate table for each type (since they each have their own set of fields), and search across the appropriate table with SQL. So, for example, you can create a table with two fields (I'm using SQLite here, which doesn't require types for fields):

```
create table Object1 (field1, otherObjectSpecifiedField);
```

This table can then have data inserted into it:

```sql
insert into Object1 values ("field1value", "otherfieldValue");
```

Filtering uses standard SQL:

```sql
select * from Object1 where field1 = "field1value";
```

As I mentioned, this could also be done with a NoSQL database such as MongoDB. That would look something like this in the Mongo CLI:

Create table and insert first object:

```js
db.test.insert({ id: "TypeId", field1: "value1", otherObjectSpecifedField: "value2"});
```

Select an object from the table:

```js
db.test.find({id: "TypeId", field1: "value1"});
/* { "_id" : ObjectId("57cf97060216d33b891615ba"), "id" : "TypeId", "field1" : "value1", "otherObjectSpecifedField" : "value2" } */
```